# up-casting std::shared_ptr using std::dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, upcasting

I'm starting to work with smart pointers in C++0X/11 and I've run into a peculiar situation.
I want to up cast an instance of an object using shared_ptr.

Class Extend inherits from class Base, where Base class has a virtual destructor in order to make it polymorphic (otherwise dynamic_pointer_cast complains about non-polymorphic class casting).

if therefore:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> obj = std::make_shared<Base>();
```

and then I do:

```
obj = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Extend>(obj);
```

1. Is it safe ?
2. What happens to other pointers to the object ? Is only obj treating it as Extend, while other shared pointers will still treat it as Base?
3. Is it safe to up-cast same instance or should I do something else ?

EDIT: Thank you for the answers. The real reason I was asking this question was to handle XML documents usign a SAX parser, but I got carried away with up/down casting.
What I sort of wanted was:

```
std::shared_ptr<Extend> ex = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Extend>(obj);
obj = ex;
```

But it makes no sense at all, instead I'll just use an object factory.

Comment: Given class B {}; class D : B {} the conversion from a B* to a D* is **down** casting, while the conversion from a D* to a B* is **up** casting. I have the feeling you have the directions the other way around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an up-cast, but a down-cast (you're casting from a less to a more derived class). However:

> Is it safe?

Yes, it is safe, but since you are trying to downcast a pointer to an object whose run-time type is not `Extend`, you will get a null pointer in return.

> What happens to other pointers to the object? Is only obj treating it as Extend, while other shared pointers will still treat it as Base?

You have a misconception here: downcasting a pointer to an object doesn't transform the object. If the object is not of the target type, you won't get a downcasted pointer to it. The type of the pointed object (of *any* object) is determined at compile-time and won't change.

> Is it safe to up-cast same instance or should I do something else ?

Not sure what you mean here, the formulation of this question probably stems from the above misconception. However, this instruction:

```
obj = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Extend>(obj);
```

Will make `obj` a null pointer. The assignment itself is legal, since you *can* assign a (smart) pointer to a derived class to a (smart) pointer to a base class. However, since the right side of the assignment evaluates to a null pointer (because of what written above), you will eventually get a null pointer assigned to `obj`.

Since you are basically just resetting `obj`, if `obj` is the last shared pointer to the object created through `make_shared<>()`, this object will be destroyed after the assignment above is performed.

Comment: yes of course, and I just realized that I'm going at it the wrong way. Thank you. What I've been trying to do is up-cast a class member from base to extend.

Comment: The final question is surely about type-casting `obj` and then storing the result back into the same `obj` variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can only down cast to a super type if the underlying object really is of that type. Casting can't suddenly give your underlying object new properties.

```
std::make_shared<Base>();
```

Will, under the covers call: `new Base`.

Which means that you can't:

```
obj = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Extend>(obj);
```

Any more than you could use `dynamic_cast` on a `new Base` to make it into something that it isn't.  You'll need to `make_shared<Extend>` and then pass it around using a `shared_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: yeah I figured this out when I tried calling a method from class extend. Funnily enough the compiler didn't complain about the line where I was up-casting. So up-casting a std::shared_ptr is out of the question ?

Comment: No it isn't out of the question, but you can only down cast to a super type if the underlying object really is of that type.  Casting can't suddenly give your underlying object new properties.